# When I am running scripts with IE in robot framework, I am getting below error:WebDriverException: Message: Invalid timeout type specified: sessionId

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When I am running scripts with IE driver in robot framework, I am getting the  below error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Invalid timeout type specified: sessionId
```

**Code:**

```
Open Browser    ${url}  ie  
Maximize Browser Window     
Input Text  ${x_username}   ${d_username}
```

I am using IEDriverServer with version 3.13. Could you please help me why I am  getting this error. Same script is working fine with chrome and firefox.

Comment: Can you share the version of IE and IE driver?

Answer (score 0):

Some people [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4445) have similar issue. Seems that IEDriverServer v5.0.0 works. Have you tried?